How to connect two VPC in same GCP project without Peering
In GCP project i have two VPC
VPC-1 & VPC-2 i would like to connect VM1 from VPC-1 to connect to VM2 in VPC-2
Both VPC-1 & VPC-2 are in same project & same Region.
i can't do VPC peering due to limitation, any other suggestion like using Cloud DNS or so ?
Have exposed VM-1 in VPC-1 with internal load balancer,
If i can use Cloud DNS what's exact configuration private zone or Peering i need to use ? (Ping or Curl not working however nslookup is fine it's able to resolve IP at-least)
End Goal
Why i want to do is due to Redis Private connect
VPC-1 is connected to Redis instance with private connect as multiple VPC can't connect to Redis instance. So service running in GKE on VPC-2 can't connect privately to Redis instance.
i am thinking to run Proxy instance(Twemproxy) on VPC-1 which will connect to Redis & Forward to VPC-2 GKE service.
Don't want to use Hub-spoke or Shared VPC/Transit VPC if possible to make it more simpler way.

If all that you're doing is sharing the redis instance, then your solution should work.  I've done the same as you, except used an SSH tunnel instead of twemproxy as I wanted a way to secure the traffic without doing peering or setting up a VPN.

Could you please share are you using Cloud DNS as private zone or peering ? i tried but not working for me ping or curl not working as expected. So i doubt on Cloud DNS exact configuration need to use as private zone or peering ?

NOTE: I use this solution for a non-production workload, so please do your own testing to determine whether it's appropriate for you.

Within the GCP project that contains the Redis instance, I have a public VM that's simply used to facilitate an SSH tunnel.  It is contained within the same VPC that the Redis instance is peered to.
Within the other GCP instance, I have another private VM that's used solely for establishing the the tunnel to the first VM.  From that VM I issue the command:
gcloud compute ssh \
  redis-proxy-user@THE_NAME_OF_PUBLIC_VM \
  --project foobarbaz \
  --zone us-central1-a \
  -- \
  -NL \
  0.0.0.0:6379:THE_PRIVATE_IP_FOR_REDIS:6379

From this, my workloads in the second project can connect to the private VM's IP on port 6379.

Perfect many thanks for sharing, details how your google cloud dns config looks like ? what connecting both vpc together ? or you using external IP of instance THE_NAME_OF_PUBLIC_VM ? As for me both of VPC in same project i tried DNS but not working as expected.

what i guess, Cloud DNS alone cannot directly connect VM instances in different VPCs. However, Cloud DNS can facilitate easier resolution of internal IP addresses once the VMs are connected through other means such as VPN or VPC peering. To connect VMs in separate VPCs, you still need a networking solution to route the traffic between the VPCs.
